# Гравитация в консольном тетрисе и ООП

Tags: python, ооп, разработка-игр

я новичок и решил написать самый простой тетрис в консоли, и столкнулся с проблемой ,которая как я понимаю связана с ООП, я могу написать гравитацию( функция при вызове должна сдвигать летящие фигуры на клетку вниз) которая будет учитывать каждую клетку, но это будет не тетрис, будут такие баги:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем я хочу понять как перейти от обработки каждой клетки к обработке фигур (гравитация и столкновения)
Вот код , пока что особо ничего нет, только две функции , одна закрашивает пиксель по координатам , другая очищает. В моем код клетка , это два символа, экран хранится в списке списков. Код работает только в консоли из за cls||clear

```
import time
import os

screen = [[".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."],
      [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]]
defaltscreen = screen


def printscreen():
    for line_words in screen:
        for word in line_words:
            print(word, end="")
        print("\n", end="")


def pixelfill(x, y):
    stroka = screen[- y]
    stroka[x * 2 - 2] = "["
    stroka[x * 2 - 1] = "]"
    os.system("cls||clear")
    printscreen()


def pixelclear(x, y):
    stroka = screen[- y]
    stroka[x * 2 - 2] = "."
    stroka[x * 2 - 1] = "."
    os.system("cls||clear")
    printscreen()
```

Comment: В данный момент вы просите реализовать за вас игру тетрис в консоли. А второй вопрос лично вам, какое отношение ООП (если это действительно то про что я подумал) имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Начинайте мыслить объектами и классами. Опишите класс `Cell` (клетка). Какие у него будут свойства, какие методы? Подумайте. Потом опишите класс `Figure`, который будет состоять из клеток. Какие у него будут свойства и методы? Потом опишите класс `Board` с игровым полем. Потом `Game` с собственно игрой. И потом всё это свяжите воедино. Вот тогда и будет ООП.

Comment: Я бы не делал клетки отдельными объектами, просто описал бы координаты клеток в рамках одной фигуры, и двигал бы все клетки одной фигуры одновременно. После падения фигура просто "расформировывается" на отдельные клетки, которые становятся частью "доски", и уже никуда не падают. Либо делать отдельным объектом, но "гравитацию" применять как бы к фигуре целиком, а не к отдельным клеткам. Если фигура упала, то она останавливается целиком.